# How to make Nautilus display .psd thumbnails?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails, photoshop

is it possible to make Nautilus display Photoshop .psd files thumbnails when viewing files in the list?

If yes, what are exact steps to make it happen. Had been searching this in google, no luck so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Okay, found this one, and it worked for me with majority of .psd files:

```
#!/bin/bash

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# -- Write psdthumbnailer
# -----------------------------------------------------------
OUTFILE=/usr/lib/psdthumbnailer
(
sudo cat <<'EOF'
# bin/bash

# Arguments / Parameters %i %o %s
f_in=$1
f_out=$2
f_size=$3

# Execute Convert PSD to PNG through ImageMagick
exec convert "psd:$f_in[0]" -scale "$f_sizex$f_size" "png:$f_out"

EOF
) > $OUTFILE
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# -- Write photoshop.thumbnailer
# -----------------------------------------------------------
OUTFILE=/usr/share/thumbnailers/photoshop.thumbnailer
(
sudo cat <<'EOF'
# bin/bash
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/lib/psdthumbnailer
Exec=/usr/lib/psdthumbnailer %i %o %s
MimeType=image/vnd.adobe.photoshop; image/x-photoshop; image/x-psd;
EOF
) > $OUTFILE
# -----------------------------------------------------------
# -- Set File Permissions
# -----------------------------------------------------------
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib/psdthumbnailer
sudo chmod 0644 /usr/share/thumbnailers/photoshop.thumbnailer

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# -- Add GConf Hooks to parse thumbnails
# -----------------------------------------------------------
sudo gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/image@vnd.adobe.photoshop/enable --type bool true

sudo gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/image@vnd.adobe.photoshop/command --type string "/usr/lib/psdthumbnailer %i %o %s %i %o %s"

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# -- Install Dependencies
# -----------------------------------------------------------

sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: Executing all steps mentioned below didn't produce any results nor errors along the way. After a reboot, icons didn't generate for psd at all! This script however did the magic. So obviously something has been left out of initial description which is quiet crucial to make it work!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I wonder who marked this working solution for being deleted? isn't it about sharing what's working?

Comment: :) I raise my hand that was me.  Yeah it's sharing knowledge. But links only are considered low quality answer because links may become broken sooner or later  leaving this post worthless.  see http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer . Anyway, I was pretty sure you gonna edit it  or make new one as this your question :D. Now, after edit you deserve +1. It's not personal, don't take it on me. :)

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this program maintained by this developer: https://moritzmolch.com/1749

I think it's probably better than the above script as the above script did not work for me, and this one seems to be well maintained and did work for other people. It did not work for me but I think that's because trying to use the script on this page messed up my settings :(

Answer (score 0):

Install the **Ubuntu PSD thumbnailer**

```
sudo apt install librsvg2-common
```

More information:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/librsvg2-common

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it to Ubuntu 21.04 / GNOME 3 (maybe 40) version:

```bsh
# become root
sudo su 

# ensure imagemagick is there
apt install imagemagick

# create script for thumbnailer
cat <<'EOF' > /usr/local/bin/gnome-thumnbail-psd
#!/bin/bash

# Arguments / Parameters %i %o %s
f_in=$1
f_out=$2
f_size=$3

# Execute Convert PSD to PNG through ImageMagick
exec convert "psd:$f_in[0]" -scale "$f_sizex$f_size" "png:$f_out"
EOF
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/gnome-thumnbail-psd

cat <<'EOF' > /usr/share/thumbnailers/photoshop.thumbnailer
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=gnome-thumnbail-psd
Exec=gnome-thumnbail-psd %i %o %s
MimeType=image/vnd.adobe.photoshop; image/x-photoshop; image/x-psd;
EOF
sudo chmod 0644 /usr/share/thumbnailers/photoshop.thumbnailer
```

Some keys to disable specific thumnailers can be found in gsettings by org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailer. No need to adjust in GNOME 3! No need to relaiunch Nautilus! Maybe just press F5.

Comment: There's a couple of "maybe"s. Could you [edit] your answer to be a little more definate..?