# How do I fix some broken thumbnail preview settings in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails, mime-type

Okay, I wanted previews for psd files in Nautilus. So I tried the scripts found on this page: [How to make Nautilus display .psd thumnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671024/how-to-make-nautilus-display-psd-thumnails)

This did not work, so then I found this maintained PPA, and I decided to try that.

It did not seem to work either. But it does krita files in addition to psd so I made a krita file and that preview worked!

So I think the issue is that the first script I ran somehow messed up my settings so that the installed PPA won't work.

Any clue on how I can reverse the effects of the first script? I don't know enough about the internals of Linux etc to really manipulate this stuff very well. I can use Linux, and do web development but I'm not really clear on how it actually manages thumbnail settings etc. I assume that's something that the shell does etc.

Answer (score 0):

Revert what the script did

```
sudo gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/image@vnd.adobe.photoshop/enable
sudo gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/image@vnd.adobe.photoshop/command
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/psdthumbnailer /usr/share/thumbnailers/photoshop.thumbnailer
## Optionnal, you may want to keep ImageMagick
## sudo apt-get remove --purge imagemagick
```

If needed, here is how to clean the Thumbnails cache
Thumbnails will be re-ceated while browsing directories

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
```

---

Install the **Ubuntu PSD thumbnailer**

```
sudo apt install librsvg2-common
```

More information:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/librsvg2-common

Comment: I already have the libsvg2-common program installed and the thumbnails still aren't appearing

Comment: Also  I've done all the other stuff, and uninstalled and reinstalled the moritz morloch thumbnailer and it still hasn't worked yet. Not sure what to do.